# Small rank matrix free fit-parameters allow me to fit experimental data, I don't understand why

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, parameter-estimation

I'm currently trying to fit a linear experimental function that relates

$$
y^{exp} = \alpha^{exp} x^{exp},
$$

with a model that has several parameters $t_1,\ldots,t_4$, where $x = x (t_1,\ldots,t_4)$ and $y = y (t_1,\ldots,t_4)$. I will call the $y$ and $x$ sets that are the results of the simulation $y^{sim}$ and $x^{sim}$, while the arbitrary set of parameters used in the simulation are $t_1^{sim},\ldots,t_4^{sim}$.

The variation of the *real* set of parameters occurring in nature (non measured in the experiment) that generate the curve $y^{exp} = \alpha x^{exp}$ are the unknown of my problem $dt_1^{exp},\ldots,dt_4^{exp}$.

Next I write down

$$
dy^{exp} = \frac{\partial y^{sim}}{\partial t_1^{sim}}dt^{exp}_1 + \dots + \frac{\partial y^{sim}}{\partial t_4^{sim}}dt_4^{exp},
$$

$$
dx^{exp} = \frac{\partial x^{sim}}{\partial t_1^{sim}}dt_1^{exp} + \dots + \frac{\partial x^{sim}}{\partial t_4^{sim}}dt_4^{exp},
$$

that is a linear system whose unknowns are $dt_1^{exp},\ldots,dt_4^{exp}$. Since its rank is not $4$ there is no unique solution, however the following weirdness happens:

I *split* the linear system in 6 solvable ones, that are

$$
dy^{exp} = \frac{\partial y^{sim}}{\partial t_i^{sim}}dt^{exp}_i + \frac{\partial y^{sim}}{\partial t_j^{sim}}dt_j^{exp},
$$

$$
dx^{exp} = \frac{\partial x^{sim}}{\partial t_i^{sim}}dt_i^{exp} +  \frac{\partial x^{sim}}{\partial t_j^{sim}}dt_j^{exp},
$$

where $i,j = 1,2,3,4$ and $i\neq j$. The $t_i^{exp}$ parameter obtained from the solution of the $n^{th}$ linear system of equations $dt_{i,n}^{exp}$ is **different** from the $dt_i^{exp}$ solution of the $m^{th}$ linear system $dt_{i,m}^{exp}$ with $n\neq m$, of course.

**HOWEVER**,

if for example the first set of equations fits the experimental $dt_{1,1}$ and $dt_{2,1}$; the second set of equations fits $dt_{2,2}$ and $dt_{3,2}$ and the third $dt_{1,3}$ and $dt_{3,3}$, it just so happens that

$$
\frac{dt_{1,1}}{dt_{2,1}} \frac{dt_{2,2}}{dt_{3,2}} \equiv  \frac{dt_{1,3}}{dt_{3,3}},
$$

in other words, the relative change is *immutable*, regardless of how I simplify

$$
\frac{dt_{i,n}}{dt_{j,n}} \frac{dt_{j,m}}{dt_{k,m}} \equiv  \frac{dt_{i,p}}{dt_{k,p}}.
$$

Finally, even tho I don't have absolute values for $dt_i$, I do end up with exact relative ratios that depend on two free parameters $\beta$ and $\gamma$ so that $y^{exp} = \gamma y^{sim}$ and $x^{exp} = \beta x^{sim}$.

Had my mathematical knowledge been stronger I probably could have seen it coming, and even tho I hoped for some degree of self-consistency, this results holds up to the zero-machine of the computer I'm running the simulations on, regardless of the arbitrary set of simulation parameters that I choose. **WHY?** It looks like, despite a non-maximal rank matrix being non-invertible, the ratio between **any** solution of the set of the *split* system is constrained to *maintain* these relative ratios,

- Does this thing have a name?
- Is it so trivial that it doesn't have one?
- Would it have worked if the number of the parameters $(\beta,\gamma)$ plus the rank of the original matrix $(2)$ was **not** equal to the number of parameter $(t_1,\ldots)$ of the model?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special property of exactly this case, two linear equations in 3 variables, $Ax=b$ with $A=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$. With the Cramer rule the ratios can be expressed as
$$
\frac{x_{1,1}}{x_{2,1}}=\frac{\det(b,a_2)}{\det(a_1,b)},~~
\frac{x_{2,2}}{x_{3,2}}=\frac{\det(b,a_3)}{\det(a_2,b)},~~
\frac{x_{1,3}}{x_{3,3}}=\frac{\det(b,a_3)}{\det(a_1,b)},~~
$$
Up to the sign, there are 3 factors on the right that cancel in the product
$$
\frac{x_{1,1}}{x_{2,1}}\frac{x_{2,2}}{x_{3,2}}\frac{x_{3,3}}{x_{1,3}}=-1.
$$

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your feedback, I currently don't understand why the 3 variable case would be exactly my case, I will think about it, however I get the gist, I now know what to look for, thank you again!

Comment: You only considered the partial systems where $dt_4=0$ is not involved, so one can reduce the system by this variable.

Comment: I understand, thank you very much, I appreciate a lot